# How to read this log cat?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-asynctask, logcat

I have two OnItemClickListeners and two buttons for them and one listview and 2 adapters. Each button will set the adapter list:

```
lv.setAdapter(adapt);
lv.setAdapter(adaptb);
```

It works the first time I run it, but when I click the button again, these red lines show in the log cat and stop the app.

```
09-08 17:51:32.605: W/dalvikvm(24630): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41af9360)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at com.example.gdrgrg.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:51)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2306)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1622)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2141)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4369)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1003)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4369)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4369)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1679)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1537)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1450)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4369)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13844)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4369)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1890)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1706)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1009)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4243)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4911)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: CustomListAdapter.java:51 this line have java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: what is this means ? and what should i do?

Comment: if you don't share code, we can't know exactly, but CustomListAdapter calling getView() with empty data array, asking for item at position 0\

Answer (score 1):

```
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
09-08 17:51:32.635: E/AndroidRuntime(24630):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
```

These lines indicate that you are trying to reach th item 0 of your ArrayList but your Arraylist is empty. You should check your code. You must fill your Arraylist before getting an item of it.

Comment: yes so it means i first add and then set adapter right?